# Why would zombies stop being detected when you turn on Xcode's zombie tracking?

Tags: ios, xcode, zombie-process

We have an App that is receiving an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error between ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear methods.

The console shows this when the error occurs:

```
SChartDateFrequency object to negative or zero - a default of 1 has been set.
From: SChartDateFrequency = { Y=2147483647, M=2147483647, W=2147483647, D=2147483647, h=2147483647, m=2147483647, s=1 }
2014-06-07 20:00:53.066 TheApp[2741:60b] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e55330
(lldb)
```

If we turn on zombie tracking in Xcode, it says we have a zombie with this error:

```
2014-06-08 09:45:28.043 TheApp[3347:60b] *** -[CFNumber compare:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x178eb2b0
```

Yet, if we turn on Xcode's Zombie tracking instrument, the App no longer crashes.

It is as if turning on the diagnostic test, temporarily "cures" the patient.

What is the cause of this? What would we do next to try to track down the source of this error?

Comment: Zombies prevents objects from deallocating.  So if your error is sending a message to a deallocated instance... well... if zombies prevents deallocation, guess that object isn't deallocated, is it?  Meanwhile... there are two distinct errors here.  One is an unrecognized selector, the other is deallocated instance... these are different sorts of errors.

Comment: Yet - isn't the Zombie tracking instrument supposed to leave a flag when messages are sent to deallocated instances?  Why would the Zombie tracking tool suddenly stop messages being sent to deallocated instances - doesn't that defeat the purpose of the tool?

Comment: I don't know exactly.  I don't know a whole lot about Zombies.  The **main** reason I was commenting was to make sure you realized you have two VERY different exceptions here.

Comment: Are they really two different exceptions? Others have noted that you can get an unrecognized selector error *because* the instance with the method has been deallocated. Both exceptions would thus be from the same event. Couldn't that be the case?

Comment: They could potentially be related.  But even if you fix the deallocation issue, you still have an issue.  Something somewhere is trying to call `length` on an `NSNumber` object.  It can be the result of calling `compare:` on something you have incorrectly cast as a string when it's really an `NSNumber` perhaps.